# How to get a "Type Mapping" function typed correctly

Tags: typescript

I have a *type* which is for a function which maps from one type **I** to another type **O** (aka, *input* and *output* types). It looks like this currently:

```
export interface IFunctionalMapping<I, O, K extends keyof O> {
  [prop: Extract<O[K], string>]: (input: keyof I, obj?: I) => K;
}
```

With the idea that one would use it like so:

```
export interface IFunctionalMapping<I, O, K extends keyof O> {
  [prop: Extract<K, string>]: (input: I) => O[K];
}

export interface IInput {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
}

export interface IOutput {
  fullName: string;
}

const mapping: IFunctionalMapping<IInput, IOutput> = {
  fullName: (i) => `${i.firstName} ${i.lastName}`
}
```

The goal would be that the properties for *mapping* would be constrained to valid properties of `IOutput` and that the type exported by the function would be of the type of `IOutput`'s property type.

It seems I'm not doing things 100% right as first off all I get an error on the `IFunctionalMapping` interface:

[image]

Which I would have thought would be avoided by my use of the **Extract** syntax.

Second, my attempt to type `mapping` to **IFunctionalMapping** complains that it needs 3 types ... I would have though that `K extends keyof O` would not need to be passed in as it's implied by the definition of O. But clearly I must be wrong about that too.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to use a mapped type to map the types of `IOutput` :

```
export type IFunctionalMapping<I, O> = {
    [K in keyof O]/*?*/: (input: I) => O[K]; // If you don't want all properties to be required, uncomment the ?
}

export interface IInput {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
}

export interface IOutput {
    fullName: string;
}

const mapping: IFunctionalMapping<IInput, IOutput> = {
    fullName: (i) => `${i.firstName} ${i.lastName}`
}
```